# Is there any way to delete more than one item at a time in Django Admin?

Tags: django

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems there should be a way to delete more than one item at a time within the Django Admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be able to click on a model.  On the [screen](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.2/_images/djangoceleryadmin2.jpg) with a list of entries you can select checkbox for whichever entries you want to delete.

in the `action` dropdown select delete.

Comment: Wow, I feel like a total moron for not seeing that. Thank you, it's a lifesaver.

Comment: @chawk don't feel bad my first couple weeks with django i didn't realize it either.  I'd click on individual entries and delete them manually